# I would like to know based on which time zone or locale the MAQL time marcos 'THIS', 'PREVIOUS', 'NEXT' work

Tags: time, macros, gooddata

I would like to know based on which time zone or locale the MAQL time marcos 'THIS', 'PREVIOUS', 'NEXT' work.
I would also like to know whether it is possible to adjust GoodData project default time zone or locale to the local time zone or regional locale like JST by project and how and how available it is if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up custom timezone using our API or grey pages. You can go directly to this URL:

https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/md/PROJECT-ID/service/timezone

and setup your custom timezone. Check out the article:

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/setting-a-custom-time-zone-for-your-project